# Git rebase "branch segment" (need something like a --from parameter?)

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

How can I do a git rebase that would so something equivalent to `"take commit FROM commit c1 to branch tip of branch X, and transplant them onto other branch A2"`?

Visually, I need to do a rebase that would get me from this tree:

```
----------------...---*----------*----*---...---X
  |  \---...---A1     master     c1   c2
  \----...--A2
```

...to this one:

```
----------------...---*master
  |  \---...---A1
  \----...--A2---*----*---...---X'
                 c1'  c2'
```

I first thought the `--fork-point` param was what I needed, but the result of trying to use it was "pure WTF" for me, guess it does something completely different, so I reverted to state before this failed attempt (what I did was: `git checkout X; git rebase A2 --fork-point master` ...maybe using c2's hash instead of master would've been the right thing, but the result of thing above was so incomprehensible to me that I totally abandoned this track...)

---

(P.S. I don't want to be told "why this is a bad idea". I know what I need, I have a clear picture of how commits should move around, and I also have a good understandings of all the changes that happened in between to what files, so I don't anticipate a conflict, and in case one happens I'm confident I can resolve it correctly.)

Comment: `--fork-point` is a complicated little beastie that uses the upstream branch's reflog to attempt to skip commits that used to be in the upstream, but were rebased away. That's definitely not what you want—what you want is the way `--onto` splits the responsibility of `git rebase`'s `<upstream>` argument in half, so that it merely limits which commits are to be copied, rather than also setting the target.  See Gautam's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.`git cherry-pick`

```
git checkout A2
git cherry-pick C1^..X
```

2.`git rebase --onto`

```
git rebase --onto A2 C1^ X
tip=`git log -1 --pretty=%h`
git checkout A2
git reset $tip --hard
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `git rebase --onto`?

Specifically, if your goal is to cherry-pick the commits of `source_branch` over `target_branch`
(i.e. commits Cy & Cz over commit C6)

```
           C6 o           => target_branch
              |
           C5 o  o Cz     => source_branch
              |  |
           C4 o  o Cy
              |  |
           C3 o  o Cx     => some_intermediate_branch
              |  |
           C2 o---
              |
           C1 o
```

1. git checkout target_branch
2. git rebase --onto HEAD Cx source_branch

Note that commit `Cx` will *not* be picked - only commits `Cy` & `Cz` will be picked and applied above commit C6.

Comment: nice detailed answer. I marked EplieKay's as answer though, because he gave 2 ways to do it plus and extra useful tip. anyway, thanks!